# Does strong stochastic ordering exist?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions, order-theory

For two probability measure $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $\mathbb{R}$, we call $\mu$ is *stochastically smaller* than $\nu$ (i.e., $\mu\leq\nu$) , if $\int f \, d\mu\leq\int f \, d\nu$ for any nonnegative bounded increasing measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

There is a fact that $\mu\leq\nu$ is equivalent to $F_\mu(x)\geq F_\nu(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, where $F_\mu(x)$ and $F_\nu(x)$ are the cumulative distribution functions of $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively.

Another fact is that, $\mu\leq\nu$ is equivalent to $\int f \, d\mu\leq\int f \, d\nu$ for any nonnegative bounded increasing measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with Lipschitz constant less or equal to $1.$

I'm curious about whether there is a *strong order* in this ordered space. That is to say, can we find some topology in probability space such that, there exists two probability measure $\mu$ and $\nu$, and their open neighborhood $\mu\in U$, $\nu\in V$ in this topology such that, $\tilde{\mu}\leq \tilde{\nu}$, for any $\tilde{\mu}\in U$ and $\tilde{\nu}\in V$.

I guess we cannot find such open sets in weak convergence topology, or Wasserstein metric $W_p$, or total variation distance topology. I cannot strictly prove it. The intuition tells me that for any $\mu\leq\nu$, perturbate the distribution function of $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that it changes little near $-\infty$ will cause contradiction.

The same question also exists for other partial order in the probability space.

Any advices will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what if $\mu = \nu$?

Comment: yes, discrete topology is valid for this case

Comment: isn't it the case that that's the only topology valid in this case then?

Comment: Infinite  Wasserstein Distance topology is a nontrivial example here.

Comment: no, it's not. since there will be some measures in a neighborhood of $\mu$ that are not dominated by $\mu$. My point is that your definition per se only seems to work for discrete topology regardless of the order, since in particular it must work for $\nu = \mu$

Comment: My definition is "there exists $\mu$ and $\nu$ and their neighborhood" not any $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a distance on probability measures by the smallest $c$ such that there exists a coupling giving mass $1$ to a $c$-neighbourhood of the diagonal. Many pairs would be infinite distance apart (you can turn it into a finite distance by taking the inf with $1$ if you want) but it would have the property you're looking for if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much! The construction is very interesting! For compactly supported probability measure, this metric can avoid the explosive growth of support. So, for example,  the probability measure $\mu$ supported in [0,1] and $\nu$ supported in [2,3], and their small neighborhood under this metric can meet the strong order requirement.

Comment: @JinxiangYao It seems that this distance also goes under the name of $\infty$-Wasserstein distance which makes sense. This may help when looking for literature.

Comment: Yes, I found some references to Infinite Wasserstein Distance, that helped me a lot in understanding its difference with $W_p$, especially their essential difference here whether the  strong stochastic order exists. That's really interesting. Many thanks!

Comment: Let's say the coupling of $\mu$ and $\nu$ gives almost all the mass to the diagonal with just a little bump under it. They will satisfy the stochastic ordering, but how their neighborhoods will happen to satisfy it as well?

Answer (score 2):

First, for the discrete topology, $U := \{\mu\}$ and $V := \{\nu\}$ are open and have the property wanted. Surely this is excluded. For the weak convergence topology, the Wasserstein metric and the stronger total variation topology its always impossible to find open neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ with the desired property.

It suffices to consider the total variation topology. For any neighborhood $U$ of $\mu$ there is $\tilde \mu \in U$ with $\tilde \mu \not\leq \nu$. Of course we assume that $\mu \not= \nu$.

For let $\mu = \mu_1 + \mu_2$ with $\mu_1$ discrete and $\mu_2$ continuous (i.e. with continuous distribution function). Let $\epsilon$ be the distance of $\mu$ and the complement $U^c$ of $U$. Of course $\epsilon > 0$. Now if $\mu_1 > 0$ there is $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < \mu_1(\{x\})$. Let $\tilde \epsilon := \min\{\epsilon/3,\mu_1(\{x\}\}$. Assume that $\nu((-\infty,y]) > 1-\epsilon$. Then $\tilde \mu := \mu - \tilde \epsilon \delta_x + \tilde \epsilon \delta_y \in U$, but $\tilde \mu \not\leq \nu$. If $\mu_1 = 0$ we proceed similarly. We cut some part of $\mu$ with mass $\epsilon/3$ and add some $\epsilon/3 \cdot \delta_y$ with large $y$ to $\mu$ as in the former case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What does "$\epsilon$ be the distance of $\mu$ and $U^c$" mean?

Comment: We have a metric $d$ and $d(\mu,U^c) = \inf \{d(\mu,\rho) \colon \rho \not\in U\}$. Note that my conctruction can be adapted (with some caution) to measures with bounded support.

Comment: It is right. But we have to prove that there are no such two subsets $U$ and $V$ of Probability measure space, such that $\mu\leq\nu$ for any $\mu\in U$ and $\nu\in V$. It seems not equivalent to the fact that for any neighborhood of any $\mu$, there is $\nu\in U$ such that $\mu$ is not order related to $\nu$.

Comment: My result is even stronger! Note that $\tilde \mu \not\leq \nu$ implies that $\tilde \mu \leq \tilde \nu$ cannot be true for all $\tilde \mu \in U$ and $\tilde \nu \in V$.

Comment: Yes, that's great! I misunderstood symbols.